# Text wrapping around truly floating content

Tags: floats

I've read a lot about the `wrapfig` package (and some others, like `picinpar`, `picins`), but I wonder if there's any possibility to have text wrapping around floating content that gets automatically positioned using the usual specifyers like `[t]` or `[b]`?

Here's an illustration of what I'd like to achieve:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+
|                   |                   |
|     ------------  |  -----  +-------+ |
|     ------------  |  ---    | [t]   | |
|     -----         |  -----  |       | |
|     ------------  |  -----  +-------+ |
|            -----  |  -----   ---      |
| +-------+  -----  |  -----            |
| | [b]   |  -----  |  ------------     |
| |       |  -----  |  ------------     |
| |       |  ---    |  ------------     |
| |       |  -----  |  ---------        |
| +-------+  -----  |  ------------     |
|  ------    -----  |  ------------     |
|                   |                   |
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

As you can see, it I'd additionally love the wrapped content to (optionally) extend into the margin.

I've made a handfull of books with this kind of page layout using OpenOffice Writer and even (please, don't beat me!) MS Word, but so far I haven't found any solution to this in LaTeX.

Here's a minimum (non-)working example, featuring two regular floating figures (figs. 1 and 2), which behave nicely, and two `wrapfigure`s (figs. 3 and 4), which extend into the margin, but do not float in any way:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\section{Some Section}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[!b]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image.png}
\caption{This floats nicely to the bottom of the page}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[!t]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image.png}
\caption{And this floats nicely to the top of the page}
\end{figure}

\blindtext
\blindtext

\begin{wrapfigure}{O}[\marginparsep+\marginparwidth]{\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image.png}
    \caption{This {\em should} float to the bottom of the page}
\end{wrapfigure}

\blindtext

\begin{wrapfigure}{O}[\marginparsep+\marginparwidth]{\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image.png}
    \caption{This {\em should} float to the top of the page}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

The task is to make the two wrapped figures (figs. 3 and 4) float to the top or bottom, respectively -- be it using the `wrapfig` package, be it by some other means.

Comment: Short answer is no. There is  a much longer answer that includes the phrases "possibly", and "more easily in lualatex" and "not implemented as far as I know".

Comment: So the not-so-short answer might reveal a loophole how to do this with plain LaTex after all? Anyway, I'd be willing to try switching over to lualatex if it was possible there. Can you provide (a link to) more information about a possible lualatex solution?

Comment: When you say you did this in OpenOffice Writer and MS Word, how did you specify the position of the floats? Did those software position them automatically and have text flow around them?

Comment: Short answer is yes. Well, let's not talk about MS Word -- it's been 16 years since I did that book project in Word, and I remember that placing images was a real pain and only worked with a lot of manual fiddling, praying and swearing. (To my knowledge, it hasn't improved since then.) But yes, in Open/LibreOffice, it is possible to attach (or "anchor") an image to a paragraph, but to specify its location relative to the page the paragraph happens to be on -- like "top of text area and 8 cm from inner margin". [to be continued in next comment]

Comment: [continuation from previous comment] And if the paragraph moves to a different page, the image also moves to the new page and places itself exactly as previously specified (possibly mirrored, if accounting for even/odd pages is activated). This is actually pretty cool, but requires a lot of mousing. And that's why I'd love to be able to do this kind of image placement (in particular the "top of page" and "8 cm from inner margin" part) in LaTeX -- no mouse required, just type what you want, and -- last, but not least -- superior typesetting. ShreevatsaR, does this answer your question?

Comment: @TorstenCrass Yes it answers the question, thanks — that information would be helpful to anyone trying to answer the question.

Comment: That may be cool, but it doesn't seem to be exactly what you're asking LaTeX to do.

Comment: People would be more inclined to experiment if you provided a minimal working example to play with.

Comment: Done -- although it is not really a _working_ example... ;)

Comment: If you want images with about the half  of the text width, consider use a two column document. Then the floats then can be placed nicely where you want, obtaining a similar  layout, but the text is now more legible, because the short lines, and because they are always equally short.  Not surprisingly many international journals are using two column, whereas I do not remember any scientific journal  using tables or figures  wrapped with text in one column. (that remember me informal magazines or formal  publications but from the  XIX century).

Comment: Fran, thanks for the stylistic advice, but let's just assume I desperately want that 19th century one-column look in spite of its possible legibility issues and focus on the more technical aspect on how to achieve it.

Comment: A quick scan of my (Physics) bookshelf shows that this is used (but not commonly) in books: Rather nice example: [Jenkins and White -- Fundamentals of Optics (archive.org)](https://archive.org/details/FundamentalsOfOptics).  A more modern example Is Ohanian -- Physics (1st year undergrad general text)

Comment: Chris, your comment prompted me to scan my own collection of (physics, chemistry and biology) textbooks too, and admittedly I didn't find any specimen exhibiting the layout I'm after. In fact, quite a few of those books featured a two-column layout as suggested by @Fran - something I never actually realized when I was regularly using them some 20 years ago... But anyway, this is not the point - I'm not about to write a textbook, and I'd still like to know if (and if yes: how) it might be possible in (Lua)LaTeX to position text-wrapped figures right to the top or bottom of a page. 1 day to go!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message on the question says

> I'd love to see either a general recipe for the kind of layout I'm after or a definite explanation why this is impossible in (La)TeX.

So here's a (definitely non-definitive) explanation of why/how this is (im)possible in (La)TeX, and a potential recipe for this kind of layout.

To a first level of approximation, this is how TeX works:

- As TeX reads your input, each paragraph is turned into a sequence of boxes (the individual characters in each word), glue (between words, between sentences), and penalties (potential hyphenation points, etc.).
- This sequence is broken into lines of the specified width: each line becomes a horizontal box. (By default each such box has equal width, that of the text area, but TeX specifying the "paragraph shape": the width of each line.)
- A vertical list is accumulated, consisting of these horizontal boxes. At some point this vertical list is broken off and shipped out as a page, along with things like headers and footers.

Floats (in the traditional sense, not the sense of this question) enter into the last step in some complicated way in LaTeX.

In your case, suppose we have decided, based on the specification, where to place your floating content (which I'll call insets). (This may require two passes, to include your floating insets that need to be placed before the paragraph in which they are mentioned.) Extending something into the margin is no problem; placing something at an absolutely specified position on the page is not difficult; there are standard ways to do it. The only thing that remains is that for each paragraph, as we walk down the page, we need to decide the appropriate “shape”: what its width should be, on the left and right, so that it doesn't run over the inset. (Something like this BTW is also what `wrapfig` does: look for mentions of `parshape` in `wrapfig.sty`.)

As @DavidCarlisle said in the comment, this is “not implemented as far as I know”, so you would have to implement it yourself.

This is the kind of thing that is easier to program with Lua(La)TeX. A working proof-of-concept (working, say, for documents where you have only plain running text and insets, nothing else) would be at most a few hours’ work. For example, before you typeset each paragraph (breaking it into lines) you can keep track of how far you've come on the page, where you are relative to the inset figure, and therefore which and how many lines need to have their widths changed in what ways. Then you specify that “shape” and let TeX typeset that paragraph. Then start over with the next paragraph, etc.

But turning it into something of production quality (e.g. dealing with multiple insets whose specification may overlap, dealing with the stretch or shrink between paragraphs, and most of all doing things in “standard” ways so as to work with the menagerie of existing LaTeX packages) may take an indefinite amount of time.

Comment: ShreevatsaR, since you explained in quite some detail where the difficulties lie with my sought-after layout , I'll accept your answer. Pitty, though, that the bounty period is already over...

Comment: @TorstenCrass Oh no matter about the bounty, it doesn't make a difference to me and it successfully served its purpose of attracting at least some attention to the question. And maybe some weekend if I have a lot of time (ha ha) I'll come with some code for this and edit this answer to include it (and ping you)—or maybe someone else will.